# read input character and print the occurrence in graphical format

Tags: c

I am reading the input and trying to print all the input lowercase character in a graphical format, am able to read it and keep track of the number of time each character repeats but not able to print it in a graphical way,can u pls help me out. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int print_fun(int);
int main()  {
int ch = 0, i = 0;
int char_count[26] = {0};
printf("\nNOTE:PRESS * TO EXIT\n");
while((ch = getchar()) != '*')    {
    if(islower(ch))
        char_count[ch - 'a']++;
}
printf("\n");
for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    //printf("%c:%d\n",'a'+ i, char_count[i]);
    //printf("%c:\n", 'a'+ i, print_star(char_count[i]));
    printf("%c:\n",print_star(char_count[i]),'a'+ i);
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
int print_star(int value)  {
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < value; i++)
printf("*");
}
```

o/p: aaxyyz

```
a:**
b:
c:
...
...
x:*
y:**
z:*
```

Comment: Please show an example of how you would like it to look. "Graphical way" isn't very helpful.

Comment: @LeeTaylor: the o/p that i require have shown it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `printf` call is missing an format argument, you have this:

```
printf("%d:%c\n",print_star(char_count[i]),'a'+ i);
```

but you are passing two arguments to `printf`, as far as I can tell this is what you meant:

```
printf("%d:%c\n",print_star(char_count[i]),'a'+ i);
```

Also, `print_star` has a return value of `int` but you do not have a `return` statement, I think you meant to return `i` and in that case you should add:

```
return i ;
```

at the end. The behavior without a return at the end is undefined. Finally, it looks like you have a typo in forward declaration, this:

```
int print_fun(int);
```

should be:

```
int print_star(int value );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//int print_fun(int);
void print_star(int);

int main(void){
    int ch = 0, i = 0;
    int char_count[26] = {0};
    printf("\nNOTE:PRESS * TO EXIT\n");
    while((ch = getchar()) != '*'){
        if(islower(ch))
            char_count[ch - 'a']++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        printf("%c:",'a'+ i);
        print_star(char_count[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void print_star(int value){
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < value; i++)
        printf("*");
}
```

Comment: An answer with code but without explanation is not really an answer, I have seen several people down vote for this alone. At least put inline comments in your code.

Comment: It does not seem comments are required. But it is preferable to see your answers if necessary. ;-D he will notice the difference because he wrote the original code.